# Position:absolute & float left/right does not work well

Tags: css, position, absolute

I have problem with position: absolute and floats...

As you can see in fiddle, when you resize browser, text from left side goes below the image, but what I want is to go above the image.

When I remove *`position: absolute`* on **`.image-ipad`**, it works like that, but in my project I need image to stick on left side, and text on right side (normal)

Code:

HTML

```html
   <section class="case eat-login">
        <div class="row">

<h3 class="stick-right">Login Screen</h3>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p> 
<img class="image-ipad" src="http://www2.pcmag.com/media/images/362825-apple-ipad-mini.jpg?thumb=y" width="300px">

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
</section>
```

CSS

```css
.stick-right{
    float:right;
    clear:both;
}
.eat-login {
    position: relative;
    padding: 130px 0 130px;
    clear: both;

}
.eat-login p{
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    width: 45%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova";
    color:#9e9d9d;  
    line-height: 25px;
}
img.image-ipad {
    left:0px;
    top:40px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jt9jk2g0/6/

Thanks!

Comment: you could do it by apply `z-index: -1;` to `img.image-ipad` - http://jsfiddle.net/jt9jk2g0/7/

Comment: @MaryMelody Like this jsfiddle.net/jt9jk2g0/8/ I removed position absolute from image, but it has to be..

Comment: you could do it by switch the order of image and text - http://jsfiddle.net/jt9jk2g0/9/

Comment: @MaryMelody Yeah but you don't have position:absolute on image... I need it to stick image to the left side of browser..

Comment: you should use css [@media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for small screen size, check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/jt9jk2g0/10/

Comment: @MaryMelody Yeah, you're right, it works when I change it in media queries. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by using css `@media` queries for small screen size:

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jt9jk2g0/10/)

**HTML:**

```
<section class="case eat-login">
    <div class="row">
        <img class="image-ipad" src="http://www2.pcmag.com/media/images/362825-apple-ipad-mini.jpg?thumb=y" width="300px">
        <h3 class="stick-right">Login Screen</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.stick-right {
    float:right;
    clear:both;
}
.eat-login {
    position: relative;
    padding: 130px 0 130px;
    clear: both;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
}
.eat-login p {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    width: 45%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
    color:#9e9d9d;
    line-height: 25px;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    h3 {
        margin-top:300px;
    }
}
```